# Router problem. Page position stay the last page position when I change any router in react-router version 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I have used react-router version 6. Everything is ok. But there is a problem that is when I change any route suppose these is 2 route once about, another contact. And now I am in the middle of the about page. Now, when I click contact Route Page and router is changed but the problem is webpage still stays middle of the page. Generally when we click any link for change route page position will automatically start from the top. then we have to scroll. but react-router version 6 has this problem. the page will not start from the top position. page position is staying the last page position.

How can I solve this problem? please help me. If are you not understood my question please let me know in the comment section.

#### router file code

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "../Components/Navbar/Navbar";

const NavbarRouter = () => {
    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Navbar />}>
                <Route index element={<Home />} />
                <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
                <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    );
};
```

#### Navbar Code

```
import React from 'react';
import {Outlet,Link} from "react-router-dom"


const Navbar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <nav className="navbar position-fixed navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
                <div className="container-fluid">
                    <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">
                        Navbar
                    </a>
                    <button
                        className="navbar-toggler">
                        <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul className="navbar-nav">
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/">Home</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">About</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <Link className="nav-link" to="/contact">Contact</Link>
                            </li>
                            <li className="nav-item">
                                <a className="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
                                    Disabled
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>

            <Outlet />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `NavbarRouter` wrapper component use the `useLocation` and `useEffect` hooks to "listen" for route changes and scroll the window back to the top.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavbarRouter = () => {
  const { pathname } = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, [pathname]);
  
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Navbar />}>
        <Route index element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="contact" element={<Contact />} />
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

If you need to configure/customize the behavior for how the view is scrolled back to the top then use the `options` argument version. Set the `behavior` option to one of `auto` (*default*) or `smooth`. `auto` is the default and lets the browser decide whether to use smooth or instant scrolling.

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'auto',
});
```

[`window.scrollTo`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo)

Comment: Hey I have integrated this but there was still a problem when changing a route there is page scrolling animation How can I stop this.